# spring boot jwt ant-mather blocking request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

I'm trying to implement JWT in my Spring Boot application. I implemented `WebSecurityConfig` like this :

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/*").permitAll().
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

Inside controller I have just a few end-points, just for testing like this :

```
@RestController("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    private void signup(@RequestBody LoginCredential loginCredential){
        System.out.println("signup");
    }

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    private void signin(@RequestBody LoginCredential loginCredential){
        System.out.println("signin");
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    private String test(){
        return "test, working ?";
    }

}
```

But when I posted some data in `http://localhost:8080/login/signup` it says **404**.

Then I wrote a filter/interceptor to check where the requests end to.
And I found this : *http://localhost:8080/login/signup*

By :  `System.out.println(request.getRequestURL().toString());`

I think there is some problem in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in the antMatcher.

**How can I resolve this problem ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting 404 because your path is not correct, the correct path is

```
http://localhost:8080/signup
```

because as per [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) '/login' is logical component name.

If you wish to make this URL work

```
http://localhost:8080/login/signup
```

then you have to add `RequestMapping` to `RestController` hence you controller should look something like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
 ...
}
```